# Removing Hangouts videos from Google Photos

Tags: youtube, google-hangouts, google-photos

When I want to upload a video to YouTube from Google Photos, all uploaded videos in a private Hangouts chat are listed. Is there a way to delete these Hangouts videos from Google Photos or completely remove them from chats so that they are not listed for upload to YouTube when I'm trying to select and upload videos from Google Photos?